# Error using \pause, loops and Lindenmayer systems

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, diagrams

I'm trying to make a beamer presentation involving L-systems, and I would like to have the reveal the steps of the L-system one at a time. Currently I have the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}

\begin{center}

\def\intervalwidth{9cm}%
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{CantorMiddleThirds}{
    \symbol{X}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \symbol{Y}{\pgflsystemmoveforward}
    \rule{X -> XYX}
    \rule{Y -> YYY}
}

\foreach \level in {0,...,5}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line width = 5pt] (0,0) l-system
    [l-system={CantorMiddleThirds, axiom=X,step=\intervalwidth/(3^\level), order=\level, angle=0},fill=black];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \pause
}

\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I compile I get a PDF which does exactly as I expected, however the compiler throws an error:

```
Package pgf Error: Lindenmayer system `CantorMiddleThirds' is already defined. \end{frame}
```

which appears once for every iteration of the loop.
I am wondering which interaction is causing this error, and how to avoid it.

Comment: I don't get that error, I get `! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@doifinframe ...gfdeclarelindenmayersystem `. Is there something more needed for your code? Can you make a complete example?

Comment: Yep sorry, I've updated the code. It requires the `lindenmayersystems` tikz library.

Comment: Try to declare your new lindenmayersystem outside the frame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works without compilation error, if `\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{CantorMiddleThirds}` is moved outside the frame. Class `beamer` processes the frame contents more than once.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{CantorMiddleThirds}{
    \symbol{X}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \symbol{Y}{\pgflsystemmoveforward}
    \rule{X -> XYX}
    \rule{Y -> YYY}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}

\begin{center}

\def\intervalwidth{9cm}%

\foreach \level in {0,...,5}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line width = 5pt] (0,0) l-system
    [l-system={CantorMiddleThirds, axiom=X,step=\intervalwidth/(3^\level),
      order=\level, angle=0},fill=black];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \pause
}

\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep that would do it, thanks. I feel a bit stupid now.